# Relationships/Grid Fieldtype can replace Playa/Matrix?

Tags: matrix, playa, relationships, grid, 2.7.0

I am currently using [Playa](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa) and [Matrix](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix) to manage multiple relationships and a gallery of images.

I am at 2.5.5 and contemplating upgrading to 2.7. I looked at the changelog and I saw the new [Relationship fieldtype](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html) that support multiple relationships and the [Grid](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/grid.html) fieldtype.

Are these new fieldtypes robust enough to replace those?

**UPDATE**: I think I might have been too general/vague in my description. To clear things up, these are 3 features that I need that I am not sure is doable in Relationship/Grid

- A radio button that is a "is_default" field. This means that it should be aware of the other radio buttons in other rows in that there should only be one checked radio button at all times
- Pagination support for Grid
- Multiple relationships field inside Grid. I am aware that the new Relationship fieldtype supports multiple relationships now but the question is if it is available inside Grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "robust enough" you mean do they have basically the same features, yes.

I've used EE's Relationships without any issues. I love Grid's search:column_name feature. That's a step up from Matrix. However, since it is brand new, it does not work with as many third party fieldtypes as Matrix. I'm sure that will change in the next 2-3 months. Depending on the fieldtypes you need for your image gallery, Grid will get the job done.

Comment: Added more specific lists of features in the question

Answer (score 2):

On top of better compatibility with third party fieldtypes, Playa and Matrix also have, IMHO, better and more polished UI. For example, if your client needs to search / filter through loads of entries, Playa is better suited.

As always, what you set on using depends on the project requirements.

**EDIT:**

- Is default: not sure I get that one. To my knowledge, what you describe is not possible to automate. I just make the "default" picture (if that's what you are talking about) is always the first one. Since rows can be reordered easily, clients do get it.
- Pagination inside grid: ok with [Matrix](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/templating/field.html) (prev_row / next_row) as well as with [native grid](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/grid.html#modifiers) (prefix:prev_row / prefix:next_row)
- Relationships inside grid: available w/ Matrix and Playa and [natively](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/2.7-grid-ready-addons) too

**EDIT 2:**

Functionality-wise, these fieldtypes are pretty similar (although I haven't used grid in production yet). I am a big fan of the care and thought about usability that has been put into Matrix and Playa. The latter particularly has had nothing but praise from my users. Here is [a video compairing both options on EE insider](http://eeinsider.com/blog/native-relationship-field-and-playa-side-by-side)

Comment: Added more specific lists of features in the question

Comment: Added edits to answer said feature list + expand on original answer

Comment: Jerome, see this SE answer for radio button accross multiple rows http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1652/155