# Radio Button across Grid Rows

Tags: grid, 2.7.0

I want to have a radio button field where it acts as “is default” field for all my rows.

That is, across all the rows, only one radio button should be checked.

Is this type of radio button supported in Grid?

I am at 2.5.5 and I am using Matrix/Playa. I am contemplating on upgrading to 2.7.0. If this type of field is supported, then I I think I will upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like [MX Lone Star](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-lone-star) is what you are looking for.

> MX Lone Star is small fieldtype which you can use to replace standard
>   checkbox. But the real power of this fieldtypes is opened in
>   Matrix-like fields - you can limited choosing in this fieldtype per
>   row or/and per column.

It works with Matrix <del>, and according to [this blog post](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/2.7-grid-ready-addons) it's also Grid compatible.</del>

Also see this similar question, ["Matrix & Radio Buttons - how to make radio button part of the same group?"](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1651/matrix-radio-buttons-how-to-make-radio-button-part-of-the-same-group)

Comment: Ugh. After actually upgrading, I found out that it does not show in the Grid fieldtype options. Is this really supported?

Comment: As far as Grid goes I only know what that EllisLab blog post says (I haven't used Grid yet, only P&T Matrix). Unfortunately looking at the [changelog for MX Lone Star](http://www.eec.ms/user_guide/mx-lone-star/changelog.html) it would seem there is no way that it could be Grid compatible since the most recent release is in 2012. Probably worth [contacting Max](http://www.eec.ms/forums/). Apologies if I have led you astray!

Comment: I sent MX Lone Star's developer an email. There must be some sort of mis-communication betwen Ellislab and him. I would have appreciated it very much if they actually tested the addons first before announcing compatibility with 2.7

Comment: This type of field _does_ work with Matrix, though!